# Weird bug with embedded youtube videos in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, youtube

I have a weird problem occurring with a web page being viewed in google chrome. When viewed in ie9 / safari the embedded youtube video works fine but for some reason in chrome it just displays a black box on page load. The weird thing is the moment the page is interacted with, ie. the user scrolls down, the video will display correctly. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

The page in question is: http://core.slnmedia.com/inspiration/

There's a script on the page that will detect the width available to the right of a large tile and if there is sufficent space, the pop-out panel will display on the right. If not, the panel will display on the left. If you resize your browser window so that the 'bevis marks' tile sits at the top right corner of the screen and only has a small amount of space available on the right, then click on it, you'll see the effect I'm talking about.

The javascript function that's changing the position of the tile is below:

```
$('.large-tile').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.bw-photo').hide();
    $(this).find('.inspiration-detail-wrapper').show();    
    $(this).css("z-index", "2");   

    var profile = $(this).find('.inspiration-detail');
    if(profile.find('.content').text().trim().length == 0) {
      showData($(this).attr('id').substring(1, $(this).attr("id").length));  
    }          

    // **Depending on how much window space is available, position the panel on**left/right        
    var available = $(window).innerWidth() - ($(this).offset().left + 300);
    if(available >= 412) {
      // If enough space then show panel on right
      profile.css("left", "320px");          
    }
    else {
      // Otherwise attach left
      profile.css("left", "-368px");          
    }
    profile.show();

    $('.scrollbar-wrapper').tinyscrollbar({ size: 252 }); 
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('.bw-photo').show();
    $(this).find('.profile').hide();        
    $(this).css("z-index", "1"); 
    $(this).find('.inspiration-detail-wrapper').hide();     
  });
```

The weird thing is that the line profile.css("left", "320px"); is what causes the trouble. If you don't include this line then the video displays correctly. For some reason the positioning causes the video not to display correctly.

I hope I've explained the problem correctly - does anyone have an idea of where I'm going wrong here? It's driving me nuts!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble after a Microsoft update. I cleared my cache and cookies for the last week and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A3pIrBZQJvE?wmode=transparent" width="420"
wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410162/youtube-embedded-overlays-on-each-tab-for-ie10)