# YouTube embedded overlays on each tab for IE10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-tools, internet-explorer-10

I am running into a weird issue and can't seem to find a solution. Using either JqueryTools tabs widget or JqueryUI tabs widget when a Youtube video is embedded it keeps overlaying it on every tab. This only occurs in IE, specifically tested with IE10. Anyone know why?

I created a jsfiddle to better illustrate this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ncfbX/19/

**Edit:**

Wouldn't let me submit it without including some code, so:

```
HTML:

<div class="main">
    <div class="slides">Slides division</div>

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab3</a></li>            
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div class="inner_panel">
                <p>working</p>
<iframe width="531" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7_nyhwuEX2c?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
             <div class="inner_panel">
                 <p>Tab2 should not have a youtube video embedded.</p>     
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
             <div class="inner_panel">
                 <p>Tab3 should not have a youtube video embedded.</p>                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.inner_panel{height:350px;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

Comment: It's most likely a `z-index` issue...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion charlie. If that is so, from my understanding z-indexes have to be updated everytime a new tab is clicked. Any ideas on how to go by achieving it without actually requiring to edit the JqueryUI or JqueryTools raw source?

Comment: When you click on a new tab, does the text also show through, or just the video?

Comment: Only the video, not the text. Think it has something to do with flash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I found a fix, apparently it had something to do with Youtube not respecting the dynamically assigned z-index.

Use the following code when embedding a Youtube video under tabs inorder to get it to work correctly with IE10:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="[YOUR_YOUTUBE_URL_HERE]?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">
```

**?wmode=transparent** at the end of the URL and **wmode="Opaque"** as an extra parameter is what makes it work.

Comment: As an FYI for other folks: I had the same problem, and this remedy did not do the trick for me. What *did* work was adding ?wmode=opaque to the URL, instead of ?wmode=transparent, and I did not have to add an attribute to the iframe. Apparently, the answer works for some, but if you're like me and it didn't, then perhaps my solution may help.